# How to get the state using stateful session bean when the server crashed or server restart?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

How to get the state using stateful session bean when the server crashed or server restart?.For example:User entering the finance data in the application in that time the system is crashed or server is off.The same user accessing the application.So,He can get the same state or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered `clustering`? Most application servers provide this feature. For `GlassFish` there is this [tutorial](http://glassfish.java.net/public/clustering31.html), among the others.

In particular, you are looking for a feature called [Stateful Session Bean Failover](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahx.html#beaib).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if the server has crashed then you can't get the state back - unless you are keeping the state in the db (doable, but can be tricky).

State won't automatically be sorted out for you after a crash or restart, but you could maybe sort out a system, either to keep state in the client end, or persist data to the db after each page view.  But either way will mean you need to do some work to make your app resilient in these circumstances.